# Why sqlite distinct doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite, left-join, distinct, android-cursorloader

I am using Loader to get data from db and I have some trouble whit distinct, in simple words - distinct doesn't work. here is my code:

```
private String[] CONTACTS_COLUMNS ={
            "DISTINCT " + ContactsEntry.CONTACT_ID + " AS _id",
            ContactsEntry.CONTACT_FROM,
            ContactsEntry.CONTACT_NAME,
            CardsPhonesEntry.CONTACT_PHONE,
            CardsPhonesEntry.CARD_NUMBER
    };

@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                ContactsEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                CONTACTS_COLUMNS,
                mSelection, null, null);
    }
```

here is some code from my contentProvider:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        Cursor retCursor;
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (match){
            case PEOPLE:
                 retCursor = getAllContacts(projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri in query(): " + uri);
        }

        return retCursor;
    }

private Cursor getAllContacts(String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                                  String sortOrder){
        return sPeopleWithCardsAndPhones.query(
                mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null, null,
                sortOrder
        );
    }


static {
        sPeopleWithCardsAndPhones = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        sPeopleWithCardsAndPhones.setTables(
                ContactsEntry.TABLE_NAME + " LEFT JOIN " + CardsPhonesEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ON " +
                        ContactsEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + ContactsEntry.CONTACT_ID + " = " +
                        CardsPhonesEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + CardsPhonesEntry.OWNER_ID
        );
    }
```

what i am doing wrong and why distinct doesn't want to work?

**EDIT:**
For example: I have 1 contact in first table, and in the second table there are 2 cards linked to this contact by contact_id;

I need to show list with only 1 item (first contact) without depending how much cards it has. and now when init loader - it shows me this contact twice, but not once.

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "doesn't want to work" means.

Comment: I am sorry, please take a look for updated question

Comment: Why not define _id as primary key rather than use the DISTINCT feature?

Comment: DISTINCT is for all columns ... use GROUP BY with some aggregation function (on column which may have multiple values)

Comment: I am not sure why you are using `LEFT JOIN` here -- I would think that this would use `IN` and a sub-select. I recommend that you put Java aside for a while and use a SQLite tool (`sqlite3` on the command line if nothing else) and play around with a copy of your database until you get the query you want, then worry about converting that query into your Java code.

Comment: @KristyWelsh, cos I am usind Contact_id as unique id

Comment: @Selvin, how should I set Group_by with the cursor loader?

Comment: Depends on your needs... why are you joining the CardsPhonesEntry table? you wana show data from ContactsEntry which have some cards? then do not use columns from CardsPhonesEntry  in projection ... or use WHERE EXISTS ... if you wana show number of cards for given ContactsEntry then use `SELECT ContactsEntryStuff_columns, count(1) CARDS_NUM FROM ContactsEntry INNER JOIN CardsPhonesEntry ON PK=FK GROUP BY ContactsEntryStuff_columns`

Comment: @Selvin, this is an old method how to make querry, but how to do it with help of cursorLoader